# Translate SQL SUM from an UNION to JPQL

Tags: sql, eclipselink, jpql

Hi im using EclipseLink and need to translate the follow sql query to JPQL.

```
SELECT sum(subtotais.peso) FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(t1.peso) as peso
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.arg1 = 1 AND t1.arg4 = 2 AND t1.arg3 = 1
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(cli.peso) as peso        
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE t2.arg1 = 1 AND t2.arg2 = 2 AND t2.arg3 = 0
) subtotais;
```

I've tried this

```
SELECT SUM(subtotais.peso) FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM(t1.peso) AS peso
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.arg1 = 1 AND t1.arg4 = 2
    AND t1.arg3 = true

    UNION

    SELECT SUM(cli2.peso) AS peso 
    FROM Table2 t2 
    WHERE t2.arg1 = 1 AND t2.arg2 = 2 
    AND t2.arg3 = false
) subtotais;
```

I got these errors:
[200, 200] The right parenthesis is missing from the sub-expression.
[201, 201] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
[392, 404]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.
[404, 408] The query contains a malformed ending.

Comment: As I know jpa doesn't support UNION

Comment: how can i run out from UNION then?

Comment: Why do you need UNION at all? if both sums are equal only one will be returned. Is that what you really need?